# Performance vertex_descriptor of the Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, vertex, boost-graph

I have a doubt concerning the vertex_descriptor used to access on a vertex in a graph.
In a previous implementation of my own, I used pointers on vertices like a way to access directly on a vertex. I could implement a map if I want access an IDVertex by an integer or something else.

But in BGL, I don't understand why a vertex_descriptor is an integer ? I know it makes sens with a vector. But if I want to use a wide set of vertices like 10^6 and be able to remove any vertex of the set, I use a map. Plus, in my game, I want to be able to refering each node by the pointer integer which is more logical ?

How BGL works to link an integer with a vertex in a no_random_access_container like std::set ? The access method is always log(n) no ? Can you explain me if there is a mecanism to keep handle directly on a vertex without keeping a vertex_descirptor ?

Sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When vertex container policy is defined as vecS, setS or listS, the vertex_descriptor becomes ["value_type" pointed to by] iterator in corresponding container. The type vertex_iterator is usually an iterator type in this container.

It means access to a vertex is always O(1). Adding and removing a new vertex will cost O(logN) in case of setS and O(1) in case of listS or vecS. Removing a vertex will invalidate some other vertices in case of vecS but not listS or setS. For details see the section **Iterator and Descriptor Stability/Invalidation** at the [adjacency graph page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html).

Regarding your other question. If you want to keep a (pointer) to a data directly on a vertex, you add it as a vertex property.

Quite often you need some kind of one-to-one mapping between your data and graph vertices. It can be convenient to keep direct map as, say, boost::unordered_set and inverse map as a property on each vertex.

Comment: So if I understood, vertex_descirptor is a size_t when vecS or an iterator on the VertexListS when listS or setS. This is why we can access directly on it. But I have a question, vertex_descriptor and vertex_iterator are the same, so when we add or remove a vertex, on listS or setS, they are not invalidated. Am I right ? Of course if it is not the one we remove

Comment: Edited the answer to address your question.

Comment: Thank you soooo much ! As far as edges are concerned, when graph is directed, they are stored in the out edge lists and when the graph is bidir or undirected, they are stored in the EdgeList and the out edge Lists's elements are iteratos on it ?

Comment: It is a little more complicated as `adjacency_list<...>` stores both "incoming" and "outgoing" edges per vertex, at least for directed graph. Which containers to use is defined by corresponding template parameter and can be either vecS, listS or setS with certain trade-offs.